# Convert csv to dictionary when csv has no header

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have my data following format in csv file and I want to convert this csv data into dictionary having the first attribute as the key and the rest as values

```
user115,1,4,8,6
user142,0,2,1,11
user145,0,0,0,3
user148,5,9,22,8
user151,2,7,8,8
```

**Note: In my csv file there is no header line. I have to provide it explicitly.**

I tried to convert it using CSV DictReader using following code segment but it is giving me error/ not providing the expected outcome

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_name),'rb', fieldnames=('key','val1','val2','val3','val4'))
```

Gives me

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'fieldnames'
```

What is the correct way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csv module`.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
d = {}
with open(filename, "rU") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in reader:
        d[line[0]] = line[1:]
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'user148': ['5', '9', '22', '8'], 'user142': ['0', '2', '1', '11'], 'user145': ['0', '0', '0', '3'], 'user151': ['2', '7', '8', '8'], 'user115': ['1', '4', '8', '6']}
```

Comment: Sure you can. Try: `reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=('key','val1','val2','val3','val4'))`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that via [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, index_col=0)
d.T.to_dict("list")

>>> {'user115': [1, 4, 8, 6],
     'user142': [0, 2, 1, 11],
     'user145': [0, 0, 0, 3],
     'user148': [5, 9, 22, 8],
     'user151': [2, 7, 8, 8]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` module and this code snippet

```
def csv_dict_list(path, fieldnames):
        csv_dict_list = []
        with open(path, 'r') as csv_file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames = field_names)
            for row in reader:
                csv_dict_list.append(row)
            return csv_dict_list

path = 'YOUR/PATH/HERE/file.csv'
```

The `fieldnames` should be a list, like:

```
field_names = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E']
```

And then you just call the method

```
newdict = {}
newdict = csv_dict_list(path, fieldnames)
```